Replacing Sewer Cap with stand pipe
I bought a new washing machine and had to change locations of it due to a water line issue. In the new location I have what looks like an old 1.5 inch sewer cast iron line that when used for a dump sink but doesn't drain fast enough for the machine to keep up. However there is a newer 3 inch pvc pipe next to it that has a sewer clean out cap.
Can I remove the sewer cap and install a stand pipe for the washer. Tbis is my only cleanout cap I have.

Officially no, plumbing code doesn't allow that. A branch fitting should be a sanitary tee or wye which has a bit of curve to it so that waste water tends to flow the correct direction.
If you look in my own laundry room, however, you'll observe that a 3" male adapter does work in the threaded port of a cleanout tee... It's the wrong way to make the connection and it all may have to be removed in the event that actual sewer cleanout operations are needed. You've been warned. ;-) In my case I've gone "temporary hack" because I intend to remodel the laundry room, or perhaps that general area of the house, but haven't decided yet what it should become.
If you want to do this the right way, it would be fairly straightforward to cut a section from that PVC pipe, solvent-weld a proper wye or tee to one side of the gap, and use a rubber no-hub coupling on the other side.

A PVC pipe should be much easier to add the proper parts needed.  Cast iron, people might want a wink wink solution.
